# Is there a way to choose either GET or POST method for every input tag under <form>?

Tags: php, html

Instead of defining METHOD attribute with either POST or GET in a FORM tag, is there any method to choose POST or GET method explicitly for each INPUT tag in a FORM?

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you described your problem so that an alternative option could be explored.

Answer (score 0):

As you can only set the form's method, there is no "obvious" way of doing so.

A solution would be to alter the form action with the input's values when pressing the `submit` button.

If you want to post the content to `/submit.php` with `input1=first`, `input2=second` and `input3=get`, you would update the action to `/submit.php?input3=get` before submitting the form.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to define a new form tag around each element to do this. There is no way to set the method for an input element.

You can see available attributes for the input tag here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp